# RabbitMQ continually spawns powershell which results in 100% cpu usage

Tags: windows, powershell, rabbitmq

I have RabbitMQ 3.11.15 installed on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter version 1809.  When the service is running, I see multiple instances of powershell in the task manager and the cpu usage is at 100%.  The system is virtually unusable.  When I stop the RabbitMQ service, those powershell instances do not return and cpu usage is under 100% ("normal").

Is there a way to configure RabbitMQ such that it does not continually spawn powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the Sysinternals `handle.exe` utility in your PATH.

We are aware of the problem - Powershell is not a good fallback when `handle.exe` is not installed.

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/8700

Answer (score 1):

Windows updates were the culprit in our case which was a similar issue on Windows 2022 Datacenter

KB5027225